# Нужна ли в данном случае запятая после "случившегося"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запята после слова "случившегося"?

Мне очень жаль, но после всего случившегося(,) вы не сможете быть вместе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, но вопрос понятен, так как на этом месте делается **произносительная** (короткая) пауза:

*Мне очень жаль, но после всего случившегося // вы не сможете быть вместе.*

Предложение сложносочиненное, в начале второго простого предложения стоит распространенный обстоятельственный оборот. Но для его обособления (выделения, актуализации) требуется **обоснование.**

Например: *Мне очень жаль, но вы, после всего случившегося, не сможете быть вместе.* **В середине предложения** (между подлежащим и сказуемым) оборот нужно будет обособить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужна. С чего вдруг она может быть там нужна?
(Если очень хочется, можно поставить интонационное тире.)